# Twilio callStatusCallback for conferences not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to setup a flow where i'm using the twilio client sdk to start a conference.
Frontend creates a device and connects, which in turn calls the route I have setup in the twiml application. Then the following is returned:

```php
        $response = new VoiceResponse();
        $dial = $response->dial('');
        $dial->conference($x->getRoomName(), [
            'participantLabel' => 'A participant label',
            'startConferenceOnEnter' => 'True',
            'endConferenceOnExit' => 'True',
            'statusCallbackEvent' => 'start end join leave mute hold',
            'statusCallback' => "https://example.com/conference-call/status-callback",
            'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST',
            'callStatusCallbackEvent' => 'ringing completed initiated answered',
            'callStatusCallback' => "https://example.com/conference-call/call-status-callback",
            'callStatusCallbackMethod' => 'POST',
        ]);
```

I can get status callbacks for the conference, but not for the call that is actually initiating the conference. As such I am unable to track the call status of the one who is initiating the conference.

Inviting a participant via the API works fine, the `callStatusCallback` works when creating a participant via the rest API.

Twilio must be creating a participant in the background when we use the `Conference` term, but there doesn't seem to be a way to subscribe to the call status?

If there is no solution for this, is there a way to use the client sdk to inititate the call, then take care of the business logic only via the rest API? It seems like the twiml is not as powerful as the rest API, but i couldn't find a way to make calls from the browser without a twiml app.